# In class Bat code, which giving me error: call of overloaded ‘Bat()’ is ambiguous Bat();

Tags: c++, c++14

This code:

```
class Bat{
        public:
            Bat();
            Bat(int i=0);
            virtual ~Bat();
        protected:
            Bat(float);
};
```

...is giving me the error: `call of overloaded ‘Bat()’ is ambiguous Bat();`

Please help me find the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have both: `Bat();` and `Bat(int i=0);`.

An attempt at creating a `Bat` without specifying a parameter to the constructor could be intended to call either of these, and the compiler has no way to know which.

The usual way of dealing with the problem is to either eliminate the one that does't take a parameter, or else eliminate the default value for the one that does take a parameter.